# Should I implement a function or a method?

Tags: c, objective-c

Once in a while I encounter a C function in my colleagues' code. 
Mostly it is in some helpful objective categories,  and those functions are mostly an internal calculation of something or a comparison of values.

Since those guys are not part of the company anymore, I can't ask them why they decided to go with a C function instead of a proper objective C method.

So the question is:

Why implement certain algorithms as a C function instead of objective C method?
What are the considerations?

Comment: See John Carmack's [Functional Programming in C++](http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2012/04/26/functional-programming-in-c/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the time you'll want methods. But remember that methods imply all kinds of overhead. So, if you don't *have* to use methods, using C functions can be a clever choice.

You should choose methods if:

- other code is going to directly access that functionality. Methods are a convenient way of namespacing functions; the C way of adding cryptic prefixes does not scale.
- your architecture requires dynamic dispatch. The Visitor Pattern is a very good example of this.
- your functionality is semantically behaviour of an object. Getters/setters are an example of such functionality.

You should choose C functions if:

- performance is critical. Calling a C function tends to be cheaper than invoking a method. Mathematical helper functions could be an example.
- no other code will use that functionality – it's an internal helper.
- the functionality does not require OOP features like dynamic dispatch to be called. It may still call methods on objects internally. That is, you are writing a procedure or subroutine, not a method.
- your functionality is semantically some operation that only incidentally happens to have objects as arguments. I.e. the subject of interest is the action, not the object.

If you'd have a `private static` “method” for that functionality in Java, it's extremely likely that this should be a C function in Objective-C.

Comment: Good answer. You might add that `extern C` is used for wrapper functions, callbacks and APIs called by other languages.